# Largest family of subsets ordered by strict inclusion

Tags: set-theory

Given a set S, with cardinality $\kappa$, let F be a family of subsets of S, such that if A and B are any two members of F then either A $\subset$ B or B $\subset$ A.

Question: Can you always find F, such that card(F) = $2^\kappa$ ?

Motivation: I recently proved this is true if S = $\mathbb{N}$.

However, my proof is dependent on very specific properties of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, so I was wondering if the result could be generalized.

Proof: Let f be a bijection from $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a bijection.

For every real number r, define Q(r) to be the set of rationals < r.

Now define corresponding subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, N(r) = f(Q(r)).

Clearly, the F = {N(r)} satisfies the criterion and card(F) = $2^{\aleph_0}$

QED

Comment: Also see http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.3099v3.pdf as a supplement to Hamkin's answer